# Laravel 5.3 Middleware: Create Middleware for authentication purposes

Tags: php, json, laravel, authentication, jwt

So, I have an API that provide user login, login API will return a Json Web Token if user successfully login.

I will consume the login API in front end, everything went well and I got the Json Web Token.
But, I want to use laravel auth middleware too, for only authentic user (user with token) can move to another page. (yes, I am use route groups).

This is my route:

```
// Login
Route::get('/tera/admin/login', 'Backend\Login\LoginController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // Logout
    Route::get('/tera/admin/dologout', 'Backend\Logout\LogoutController@index');

    // Dashboard
    Route::get('/tera/dashboard', 'Backend\Dashboard\DashboardController@index');

    // Inventory
    Route::get('/inventory', 'Backend\Inventory\InventoryController@index');
});
```

with this approach, the middleware always redirecting me into laravel built in login page.

any best practice to solve this case ?

Thank you.

Comment: How does your user model look like (what traits does it use?)

Comment: I am using Lumen to create the API, so I the API will attempt directly into the API, and return true or false

Answer (score 0):

You need to either change the `Authentication Routes` in `auth()` method in the `Illuminate\Routing\Router.php` file. In Laravel `5.3`, the `auth()` method defines the following routes:

```
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

So, you can change them in this function or in your `routes` file, you can override them using the `auth` prefix:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('login', 'Backend\Login\LoginController@index');
    //Define rest of your routes here...
});
```

Alternatively, you can navigate to `app\Http\Controllers\Auth` directory where you will see different controllers handling the authentication. You will see `LoginController.php` and `RegisterController.php` in this directory. Both of these controllers contain the property `$redirectTo` that defines where to redirect the user once it has logged in. Change this property to your desired route and you should be redirected to the new route.

Comment: user login auth already done in API, so front end only get the return result (as user token and the user detail)